# Cutting image around white region using OpenCV - Android

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, android

I have an image of the eye area and I want to cut it around the white region, i.e, I just want to keep the white region of the eye with the iris inside it.

The picture bellow illustrates what I want to do, I only want to keep the region enclosed with the red line.

[image]

After searching I found that I may use contours to find the white region that I want to cut, I used these two examples to write my code:

[how to detect region of large # of white pixels using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262600/how-to-detect-region-of-large-of-white-pixels-using-opencv)

http://answers.opencv.org/question/43700/android-using-drawcontours-to-fill-region/

But, after applying contours I'm getting a totally black image. Here is my code:

```
private void match_eye(org.opencv.core.Rect area, Mat mTemplate) {
    Point matchLoc;
    Mat mROI = grayMat.submat(area);
    int result_cols = mROI.cols() - mTemplate.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = mROI.rows() - mTemplate.rows() + 1;
    // Check for bad template size
    if (mTemplate.cols() == 0 || mTemplate.rows() == 0) {
        return ;
    }

    Mat mResult = new Mat(result_cols, result_rows, CvType.CV_8U);

    /*************Here starts finding contours of the image*******************/
    Imgproc.threshold(mROI, mROI,127, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY );
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(mROI, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, 
                            Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); //finding the white region.

    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {

        if ( 10 < Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx))){

            Imgproc.drawContours(mROI, contours,contourIdx, new Scalar(0,0,255),2);
        }
    }//end for.

    Imgproc.resize(mROI, mROI, new Size (1000, 1500));
    Bitmap contour =  Bitmap.createBitmap(mROI.width(), mROI.height(), 
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(mROI, contour);

    //store the image with the found contours in the gallery: 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),contour, 
                            "testgray", "gray" );
}
```

**Note mROI in the code above is the image of the eye area.**

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.