# Not getting a countour box around the texts/tags on an X-ray image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, medical

I am trying to detect texts and remove those thick letters. The goal is same proposed by the following link: [How to detect text on an X-Ray image with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603686/how-to-detect-text-on-an-x-ray-image-with-opencv). ("to extract the oriented bounding boxes as a matrix")

Two sample images:
[Sample Image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEAOM.png)
[Sample Image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP6x0.png)

Here, the fonts L, J, C, O (from 1st image) and L, D, A, N, circle-shape (from 2nd image) must be detected. I tried the methods proposed by above link ([How to detect text on an X-Ray image with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603686/how-to-detect-text-on-an-x-ray-image-with-opencv)), however, it fails to detect the texts in the background.

Original Image --> Binary image

[Binary Image (thresholding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgloY.png)

Morph close --> Detected text

[Morph close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3wMB.png)
[detected texts (nothing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaNIw.png)

As you can see, it fails to detect the texts from the background. It just returns black image. Don't know what happened.

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, create mask, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('HandImage.png')
original = image.copy() 
blank = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Merge text into a single contour
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    # Filter using contour area and aspect ratio
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    ar = w / float(h)
    if (ar > 1.4 and ar < 4) or ar < .85 and area > 10 and area < 500:
        # Find rotated bounding box
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(36,255,12),2)
        cv2.drawContours(blank,[box],0,(255,255,255),-1)

# Bitwise operations to isolate text
extract = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, blank)
extract = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=extract)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('extract', extract)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I am new to the computer vision and image manipulation... Please help!

Update:

I have figured out the error in my code. I had to adjust and identify the right size/area of the bounding box that selected for the texts.

The code:

```
 # Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

for c in cnts:
    # Filter using contour area and aspect ratio (x1 = width, y1 = height)
    x, y, x1, y1 = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if (30 < x1 < 200 or 350 < x1 < 500) and 50 < y1 < 350:
        # Using the area above to calculate the rotation
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        translated_box = box - np.mean(box, axis=0)
        scaled_box = translated_box * 2 # 2 is scale factor
        retranslated_box = scaled_box + np.mean(box, axis=0)
        box = np.int0(retranslated_box)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (36,255,12), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(blank, [box], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
```

But I also liked the suggestion by @Mikel B, where he used a neural network method.

Comment: The approach given in the link won't work for your images. Your binary images contain a white border around the text and X-ray skeleton. And since you are using `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` while finding contours, it only picks up the border and ignores the text. You will have to analyze all the available contours in your binary image and then proceed.

Comment: those xray markers are the hopefully densest objects in the picture so you should be able to locate them with a *high* threshold. then figure out what marker you've got (analyze the shapes, L is very characteristic, a 6-corner contour) and black out an appropriate area around the located text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution in OpenCV as requested. But I leave it here in case a neural network-based solution could be of interest for anybody

First of all install the package by:

```
pip install craft-text-detector
```

Then copy paste the following

```py
from craft_text_detector import Craft

# import craft functions
from craft_text_detector import (
    read_image,
    load_craftnet_model,
    load_refinenet_model,
    get_prediction,
    export_detected_regions,
    export_extra_results,
    empty_cuda_cache
)

# set image path and export folder directory
image = '/path/to/JP6x0.png' # can be filepath, PIL image or numpy array
output_dir = 'outputs/'

# read image
image = read_image(image)

# load models
refine_net = load_refinenet_model(cuda=False)
craft_net = load_craftnet_model(cuda=False)

# perform prediction
prediction_result = get_prediction(
    image=image,
    craft_net=craft_net,
    refine_net=refine_net,
    text_threshold=0.5,
    link_threshold=0.1,
    low_text=0.1,
    cuda=False,
    long_size=1280
)

# export detected text regions
exported_file_paths = export_detected_regions(
    image=image,
    regions=prediction_result["boxes"],
    output_dir=output_dir,
    rectify=True
)

# export heatmap, detection points, box visualization
export_extra_results(
    image=image,
    regions=prediction_result["boxes"],
    heatmaps=prediction_result["heatmaps"],
    output_dir=output_dir
)

# unload models from gpu
empty_cuda_cache()
```

My results with these parameters:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks fantastic! Thank you so much for your input :)

How would you increase the size of the bounding box? I want the bounding box to be increased enough to fit the tag that's behind the texts as well? (doesn't have to fit all the way)