# Remove logo from images with using original image as a mask in OpenCv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

First of all, I'm sorry for my English..

I'm new in OpenCV, trying to remove logos in images. I found this answer in this site --> [How to use OpenCV to remove non text areas from a business card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255013/how-to-use-opencv-to-remove-non-text-areas-from-a-business-card)

I follow the steps and write these codes:

```
int main(int argc,char** argv) {


Mat eroded,dilated,img1=imread("C:\\Users\\Buket\\Desktop\\Belgeler\\Oda Kayıt Belgesi\\OKB001.jpg");
int erosion_size = 6;   
Mat elementd = getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS,
                                    Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1), 
                                    Point(erosion_size, erosion_size) );
int dilation_size = 1;   
Mat elemente = getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS,
                                    Size(2 * dilation_size + 1, 2 * dilation_size + 1), 
                                    Point(dilation_size, dilation_size) );

Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1);
dilate(img1, dilated, elementd);

Mat lastimg;
int count =0;
do{
    lastimg = dilated;
    erode(dilated, lastimg, elemente);
    max(lastimg,img1);
    count++;
}while(count < 2);
```

Now I have an image that just logo on it:

[Just logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQVwn.jpg)

And this is the source image:

[Original pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYfwi.jpg)

In the article, there's that saying "you now have an image with ONLY the logo and no text, use this image to remove the logo".
But how can i do that? I research a lot but found nothing..

Please help..

***EDIT***

```
Mat dest;

subtract(lastimg,img1,dest);
bitwise_not(dest,dest);
```

that function is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code, Hopefully it should work:

```
Mat img1=some_img;
Mat img2=some_img;

Mat dest;

cv::subtract(img1,img2,dest);
```

This performs pixelwise subtraction (img1-img2). 
find more details about it http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

Comment: This won't work, it requires the images to be of the same size.

Comment: the images she showed seemed to be of the same size and modified version of the same image file. if its the same size. then it will surely work. otherwise not. :)

Comment: if the images are of different sizes, then you have to localize the area of logo, probably go with template matching or object detection or feature detection and then blankly just remove the are of logo. but for the above problem, this is probably the best solution.

Comment: images are same size. but that doesn't work. it's output is just black picture. i want like this https://postimg.org/image/fr8r3engx/ (made by paint :) ) even so thanks for your answer

Comment: you gave "original image"-"just logo" image right??

Comment: can you post the respective image sizes?? i have tried the sae code for python and it works..

Comment: i put the parameters wrong, now it has been done! Thanks a lot!